# Laravel WorkflowSubscriber class that conditionally calls guard methods based on the current transition calling incorrect methods

Tags: laravel, symfony, laravel-5, workflow, laravel-5.7

I have an unnecessarily perplexing situation here. I'm simply trying to create a method inside this WorkflowSubscriber that checks an event's transition, creates a `$guardMethod` variable that will look something like `guardToSomePlace` and then if that method exists, call it. Here is the code for that concept:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Models\BugTypes\Bug;
use Symfony\Component\Workflow\Event\GuardEvent;

class BugWorkflowSubscriber
{
    /**
     * Handle workflow guard events.
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Workflow\Event\GuardEvent $event
     */
    public function onGuard(GuardEvent $event)
    {
        $transition = $event->getTransition();

        $guardMethod = 'guard' . studly_case($transition->getName());
        // this can be something like guardToAccepted and it 
        // calls guardToOnHold below

        if (method_exists($this, $guardMethod)) { // should fail
            $this->$guardMethod($event);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Guards the to_on_hold transition
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Workflow\Event\GuardEvent $event
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function guardToOnHold(GuardEvent $event)
    {
        dd('why is it getting here for other transitions?');
    }

    /**
     * Register the listeners for the subscriber.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher  $events
     */
    public function subscribe($events)
    {
        $events->listen(
            'workflow.bug.guard',
            'App\Listeners\BugWorkflowSubscriber@onGuard'
        );

        $events->listen(
            'workflow.bug.entered.*',
            'App\Listeners\Workflow\Bug\OnEntered'
        );
    }
}
```

It is calling the `guardToOnHold` method for multiple transitions, despite the fact that I can dd `$event->getTransition()` and it is the transition I expect and if I dd `method_exists($this, $guardMethod)` it is false for any/all methods besides `guardToOnHold`, as that's the only one that would exist after I create the `$guardMethod` variable. If I dd `method_exists($this, $guardMethod)` before the if statement it is false, but dd-ing it inside the if statement with the same event/transition gets into the if statement and dd's `true`. This is Laravel 5.7 using the Brexis/Laravel Symfony Workflow package. The transition for the event is always what I expect it to be. `$event->getTransition()` always returns one Transition Object with the correct name, froms and tos.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't releasing one event after the other? What happens if you call `$this->$guardMethod($event)` without the `if` check?

Comment: I tried that. It throws an exception for calling an undefined method like you'd expect for any transitions that do not have a guard.

Comment: Multiple events seems highly possible. If I pass a string that is identical to the result of `$transition->getName()` it behaves correctly.

Comment: If I dd the event itself, it looks accurate (has a the correct place and transition). That doesn't account for the possibility of releasing more events...

Comment: But you're `dd`ing, what about just `dump`?

Comment: I tried dump and print_r to keep it moving. It just dumps/prints one event.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually something related to what I am investigating for past 3 days. What happens is in symfony workflow when you apply a transition it call a function to getEnabledTransitions which in turn calls to doCan method and that calls to guardTransition, now the guardTransition dispatches workflow.guard event and as you have a listener (onGuard) your function gets called.

This is what I think is happening I am still not 100% sure if I am right and what should be done in such cases, maybe I need more investigation.

Relevant code:

```
// all taken from Symfony/Component/Workflow/Workflow.php
public function apply($subject, $transitionName)
    {
        $transitions = $this->getEnabledTransitions($subject);

public function getEnabledTransitions($subject)
    {
        $enabled = array();
        $marking = $this->getMarking($subject);
        foreach ($this->definition->getTransitions() as $transition) {
            if ($this->doCan($subject, $marking, $transition)) {
                $enabled[] = $transition;
            }
        }
        return $enabled;
    }

private function doCan($subject, Marking $marking, Transition $transition)
    {
        foreach ($transition->getFroms() as $place) {
            if (!$marking->has($place)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (true === $this->guardTransition($subject, $marking, $transition)) {
            return false;
        }

private function guardTransition($subject, Marking $marking, Transition $transition)
    {
        if (null === $this->dispatcher) {
            return;
        }
        $event = new GuardEvent($subject, $marking, $transition, $this->name);
        $this->dispatcher->dispatch('workflow.guard', $event);
```

Adding this here so it might help someone in future.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is in documentation, as always.
When you subscribe to `workflow.bug.guard` it will be called for all transitions. You should subscribe for specific transition with `workflow.bug.guard.transition`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).